# Private Style in a StyleSheet with preformatted text

Tags: front-end, stylesheet

I want to create a new Style in my private StyleSheet. I duplicated the Style "Text" and made some alterations. Now I want that a Cell with this style has an expression already filled in, for example "exercise 1.4" (with counters). How can I implement this in the StyleSheet, I already tried TextData[]. Seems, that I always make some syntax mistakes. How can it be done? Many thanks.

Comment: Counters and associated text need to be added within the cell frame rather than the cell body. Best to examine some examples from stylesheets that have automatic numbering, e.g. DisplayForumulaNumbered